# How to assign a has_many/belongs_to relation properly in Rails ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a rails app with articles and author model. If I have an author and a post and want to indicate that the author should be the owner of the article, or that the article belongs to the author, what ist the best practice to do so? In particular:

Does it make a difference if I set

```
my_article.author_id = author_one.id
```

or If I do

```
author_one << my_article
```

The associations that are used are

- Author has_many articles
- Articles belongs_to Author

And, by the way, what would be the best way to look it up if similar questions appear?

Comment: Your associations are set up correctly, but neither of the code examples is "right" in the sense that Rails provides a well defined pattern for this kind of stuff.  I suggest you look at a tutorial (RailsCasts is great) -- there are scores of blog examples that will help you understand.

Comment: @MrYoshiji I want to know more about this tell-don't-ask-topic Rudy brought up

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is not difference between the 3 following:

```
my_article.author_id = author_one.id
my_article.save
# same as
my_article.author = author_one
my_article.save
# same as
author_one.articles << my_article
```

To set the owner of a particular post, the most common and readable way would be:

```
post.author = author
post.save
```

OR **shorter version**:

```
post.update_attributes(author_id: author.id) # call an implicit save
```

Comment: A reminder for people like me who forgot: You cannot use do something like `Post.update_all(author: Author.first)` you will need to instead do: `Post.update_all(author_id: Author.first.id)` Due to: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all "It does not instantiate the involved models and it does not trigger Active Record callbacks or validations" (Maybe this works in rails 6?)

Answer (score 3):

*I'm assuming you mean `author_one.articles << my_article` rather than just `author_one << my_article`*

One difference between the two is that

```
author_one.articles << my_article
```

will save the change to the database immediately. i.e. it will either create the record for `my_article` if it has not been saved before or it will update the existing record to have `author_id` = `author_one.id`

whereas

```
my_article.author = author_one
```

or

```
my_article.author_id = author_one.id
```

will not be persisted until you do a `my_article.save`

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the correct way of doing that is creating a instance method on your Article class, like the following:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def add_an_article(article)
    unless self.articles.include?(article)
      self.articles << article
    end
  end

end
```

This will provide a better semantic to your model and encapsulate the logic of the association manipulation...

That way, your class also will be compliant to Tell-don't-ask principle:
http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask.

Unfortunately, most of the Rails community ignores good OO principles and prefer the easiest but not right way of doing something!

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but adding a method like this isn't really needed. Rails provides standard idioms for doing this. Also, when adding an author to an article it's the article (with the foreign key) that needs saving not the author, but this is done automatically when using `<<`

Comment: You're right about the '<<' persisting the record. Anyway, i'm not talking about the article saving itself. Im taking the question to another level, trying to show the right way of creating the association between the entities. Unfortunately, Rails community prefer to ignore some good OO principles, like Tell-dont-ask - pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask. By manipullating the collection in other object, you're asking for a resource, rather them telling the class instance to perform something...

Comment: @Rudy why does the method `add_an_article(article)` comply to the tell-don't-ask-principle better then the mehtod `articles << (my_article)`? Are you talking about the assertion not to add an article twice? If I want to prevent the stuff from being added twice, why shouldn't I tweak the `articles <<` method itself of the models in question instead of adding a new method?

Comment: @Yo, i was talking about making assumptions about things that you can't. 1- The [code]<<[/code] method exists because the Author internal property [code]articles[/code] is an array (and by calling the method outside of the object itself, you're already making assumptions about an object's INTERNAL property). 2- If you're calling [code]<<[/code] outside of the property's owner scope (inside author object, in this case), how can you ensure the object's invariants? continuing bellow...

Comment: In this case, the duplication is one of those invariants. But imagine (and, believe-me, this isn't rare at all!) that you have a case where all articles of an author must start with the letter 'A'? Well, the example isnt good, but hope you got the idea...

Comment: I think in general, Rudy Seidinger is absolutely right, but `author.articles << article` in this case is perfectly valid, since by definition `ActiveRecord` pattern mixes up 2 things: a domain model and a database manipulation object.

Answer (score -1):

Best thing is to use:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many
```

Because, author may have written many article and article can have many authors.